# Não consigo exibir todos os resultados do db - PHP e MYSQLI

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Opa, bom eu não estou conseguindo exibir todos os dados do meu database. Não sei porque é pois (talvez) não aja nada de errado com o meu codigo

Meu codigo

```
<?php
$host = '';
$user = '';
$pass = '';
$db = '';

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM 'cast_vbr' WHERE 1';
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
if($r) {
   echo $r['title'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente este codigo:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'usuario_do_banco', 'senha_do_usuario', 'nome_do_banco') or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

    if (!mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8')) {
        printf('Error ao usar utf8: %s', mysqli_error($conn));
        exit;
    }

$id = "1";

$busca_titulo = $conn->prepare("SELECT titulo FROM cast_vbr WHERE id=?");
    $busca_titulo->bind_param("i", $id);

    if(!$busca_titulo->execute()){
       echo $busca_titulo->error;
    }
    
    $busca_titulo->store_result();
    $registros = $busca_titulo->num_rows;
    $busca_titulo->bind_result($titulo);
    
    if ($registros != 0){
        $busca_cliente->fetch();
        echo $titulo;
    }
```